# Using Rails default :resources routing to create record with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails app, I'm trying to use jQuery ajax to create a new item via the default `create` method in my controller.

My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
resources :items
```

The server side code is still as it was generated:

```
  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, :notice => 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @item, :status => :created, :location => @item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @item.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$("#capture_input").focusout(function() { 
    var description = $(this).val(); 

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/items/create.json',
      data: { 
        item: { 
          description : description
        } 
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      }
    });
  });
```

This seems really straightforward, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/items/create.json"):
```

I've been able to use the default `update` method in a similar situation without any issues. What's the problem here?

EDIT: Fixed typo in routes.rb code.

Comment: what do you see when you run `rake routes`? Do you see the route for items create with POST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example lines in your controller give a clue here.

```
# POST /items
# POST /items.json
def create
...
```

The create action is simply a POST to /items.json, so you just need to change the URL you are using in your jQuery to '/items.json'.

Answer (score 1):

Something is either wrong with your example or with your code! You say in `routes.rb`you have

```
resources :workitems
```

Which means the path would be

```
/workitems/create.json
```

But in your script you try to call `/items/create.json` instead of `/workitems/create.json`.

I think you should check your routes.rb or your example.